# FB.api variables not available immediately after login

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I'm building a PhoneGap app that uses FB login. I am able to successfully login to Facebook through the app. The problem, however, is that I'm not able to store data in javascript variables immediately after the user logs in.

However, if I log out and log back in, I'm able to access the data.

**The login:**

```
FB.login(
    function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            var FBuserID = response.authResponse.userID;

            alert(FBuserID);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/user/' + FBuserID,
                success: function(response) {

                    // calls FB.api functions
                    userInfo();

                    alert(userName);
                    alert(profilePic);

                    },
                error: function() {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });

        } else {
            alert('No Success');
        }
    },
    { scope: "email" }
);
```

**userInfo()**

```
FB.api(
        '/me', function (response) {
            var userName = response.name;
        });
    FB.api(
        '/me/picture',
        {
            "redirect": false,
            "type": "square"
        },
        function (response) {
            var profilePic = response.data.url;
        });
```

If I add `alert(userName);` and `alert(profilePic);` within the FB.api calls, I am able to see the data, but they aren't accessible within the $.ajax function. Is this a simple scope issue that I'm overlooking?

**Note:** I also attempted using the $.ajax call within the `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response)` function without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does look like a simple scope issue.  You're declaring your variables inside userInfo() and then trying to access them inside the login function.

Your next problem will be that these calls are most likely asynchronous.  So, as you stated, you can use the alert function within the api functions and see the data.  Anything you want to do with the response data will have to be done within those success functions, so you'll want something like this:

```
FB.api(
    '/me', function (response) {
        doSomethingWithUsername(response.name);
});
FB.api(
    '/me/picture',
    {
        "redirect": false,
        "type": "square"
    },
    function (response) {
        doSomethingWithProfilePic(response.data.url);
});
```